# Getting Swift error when running `pod lib lint`

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Swift is very new for me. I have a Swift project that builds fine in xcode and all the unit tests pass.

However when I run `pod lib lint` I get a `no such module MyModule` error.

```
Testing with xcodebuild.
 -> my-swift-project (0.4.2)
- WARN  | source: Git SSH URLs will NOT work for people behind firewalls configured to only allow HTTP, therefore HTTPS is preferred.
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  my-swift-project/Echo/Delegates/MyModule/MyModule.swift:7:8: error: no such module 'MyModule'
```

The file in question has an import module declaration at the top of the file

```
import MyModule
```

Why might this be happening, and why does the project build in Xcode fine but not when I get to this stage?

Comment: Do you export `MyModule` code with your pod or have you setup dependencies?

Comment: setup as dependencies

Comment: Can you provide your podspec file?

Comment: @Richlewis did the below answer solve your question?

Answer (score 3):

build settings > Framework Search Paths 
Set framework search path to $(SRCROOT) and recursive.